# Remove/make transparent some parts of the form from vb .net form

Tags: vb.net

I was trying to create a form in which some of the parts are transparent i.e I can click or use the form that is open behind the current form.
I have heard of transparency key as a way to do it but couldn't figure out a way to do it.

```
Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Transparent
```

Comment: Please provide more context and/or code you wrote to help other people help you.

Comment: Ok will do from next time, new here, trying to learn, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using TransparencyKey you have to state the part of the background color that you want to make transparent.
For example:-

```
Me.BackColor = Color.Green;
Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Green;
```

this will make all the visible portions of form that are green completely transparent

Comment: @PayalSharma you **can** (and should) click the checkmark if it works